# Disable SELECT or INSERT or UPDATE or DELETE statement for specific/certain TABLE

Tags: sql

I **allowed** user to input SQL statement in the system

But there are some **data** that i want to hide from user

Is there any way that i can disable `INSERT` or `SELECT` or `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement on selected `TABLE`?

Comment: Simply don't GRANT SELECT/UPDATE etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
REVOKE privileges ON object FROM user;
```

For example:

```
REVOKE ALL ON employees FROM anderson;
REVOKE INSERT ON employees FROM anderson;
```